# How I can check android device is connected to the Internet?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi, android-internet

Is there any way to find out that android device is connected to the Internet or not. I use this function:

```
    public boolean isDeviceOnline() {     
        ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();     
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting(); 
    }
```

but this function return true if device connected to a WiFi network that doesn't include internet access or requires browser-based authentication and I want return false in this situation.

Comment: Try to ping google.com.

Comment: "but this function return true if device connected to a WiFi network that doesn't include internet access or requires browser-based authentication and I want return false in this situation" -- then make an Internet request (e.g., HTTP request) of the server that interests you. There is no concept of "connected to the Internet" -- the only thing that you can determine is whether you can contact the server that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context _context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
}

public boolean isInternetAvailble() {
    return isConnectingToInternet() || isConnectingToWifi();
}

private boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isConnectingToWifi() {
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (mWifi != null) {
        if (mWifi.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
} }
```

declare like this

```
ConnectionDetector ConnectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector(
            context.getApplicationContext());
```

use like is

```
ConnectionDetector.isInternetAvailble()
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this only check if you have a network connection? What if you need to know if that network connection has internet access? Is there a better way that trying to go to some web address?

Answer (score 0):

just try this method >

```
public boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null; // return true =(connected),false=(not connected)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

To:

```
return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected();
```

Then call it like

```
if(!isDeviceOnline()) {
    System.out.println("Not connected");
}
```